# Automatically assume value without input action

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following form where you do the math dynamically like this:

```js
$(".soma4, .soma5, .soma20").blur(function(){

    var total1 = 0;
    var total = 0;
    var total2 = 0;
    var selector = $(this)
     selector.closest(".test").find(".soma4").each(function(){
        total1 = total1 + Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));  
    });
     selector.closest(".test").find(".soma5").each(function(){
        total = total + Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));  
    });
    selector.closest(".test").find(".soma20").each(function(){
        total2 = total2 + Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));  
    });

    total3 = total * total1;
    total4 = total2 / 100;
    total5 = total3 * total4;
    total6 = total3 - total5;
    selector.closest(".test").find(".sub3").val(total6.toFixed(2));
});

$(".soma").blur(function(){

    var total = 0;

    $(".soma").each(function(){
        total = total + Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));  
    });
    
    $("#sub").val(total.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form role="form" class="limp5">
 <div class="test">
  <div class="form-group col-md-1"> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control1 Preco1 alinha soma4" name="Qttd" id="Qttd" required>
        <span class="form-highlight"></span>
        <span class="form-bar"></span>
        <label class="label3" for="Qttd">Quantidade</label>        
    </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-1" style="width: 11.099999995%; flex: 0 0 11.099%;max-width: 11.099%;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control1 Preco1 alinha soma5" name="Uniit" id="Uniit" required>
        <span class="form-highlight">€</span>
        <span class="form-bar"></span>
        <label class="label3" for="Uniit">Preço Unitário</label>   </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control1 soma20 alinha" name="Descoonto" id="Descoonto" required>
            <span class="form-highlight">%</span>
            <span class="form-bar"></span>
            <label class="label3" for="Descoonto">Desconto</label>   </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control1 soma alinha sub3" name="Vallor" id="Vallor" required>
            <span class="form-highlight">€</span>
            <span class="form-bar"></span>
            <label class="label3" for="Vallor">Total</label>         </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12" >                       
                <input type="text" class="form-control alinha" name="sub" id="sub">
                <span class="form-highlight">$</span>                       
                <span class="form-bar"></span>                      
                <label class="label3" for="sub">Total</label>        
    </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

The problem I have is that the input with `id="sub"` only takes the value if there is an action on the input with `id="Vallor"`.

I wanted it to take the value automatically without having to click on the input.
I've already tried putting this code inside the `.soma` function:: `$('#sub').focus();`
but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try using on() with 'input' as trigger, then put everything in the same callback like this:

```js
$(".soma4, .soma5, .soma20").on('input', function(){

    var total1 = 0;
    var total = 0;
    var total2 = 0;
    var selector = $(this)
     selector.closest(".test").find(".soma4").each(function(){
        total1 = total1 + Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));  
    });
     selector.closest(".test").find(".soma5").each(function(){
        total = total + Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));  
    });
    selector.closest(".test").find(".soma20").each(function(){
        total2 = total2 + Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));  
    });

    total3 = total * total1;
    total4 = total2 / 100;
    total5 = total3 * total4;
    total6 = total3 - total5;
    selector.closest(".test").find(".sub3").val(total6.toFixed(2));
    
    var total = 0;

    $(".soma").each(function(){
        total = total + Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));  
    });
    
    $("#sub").val(total.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form role="form" class="limp5">
 <div class="test">
  <div class="form-group col-md-1"> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control1 Preco1 alinha soma4" name="Qttd" id="Qttd" required>
        <span class="form-highlight"></span>
        <span class="form-bar"></span>
        <label class="label3" for="Qttd">Quantidade</label>        
    </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-1" style="width: 11.099999995%; flex: 0 0 11.099%;max-width: 11.099%;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control1 Preco1 alinha soma5" name="Uniit" id="Uniit" required>
        <span class="form-highlight">€</span>
        <span class="form-bar"></span>
        <label class="label3" for="Uniit">Preço Unitário</label>   </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control1 soma20 alinha" name="Descoonto" id="Descoonto" required>
            <span class="form-highlight">%</span>
            <span class="form-bar"></span>
            <label class="label3" for="Descoonto">Desconto</label>   </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control1 soma alinha sub3" name="Vallor" id="Vallor" required>
            <span class="form-highlight">€</span>
            <span class="form-bar"></span>
            <label class="label3" for="Vallor">Total</label>         </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12" >                       
                <input type="text" class="form-control alinha" name="sub" id="sub">
                <span class="form-highlight">$</span>                       
                <span class="form-bar"></span>                      
                <label class="label3" for="sub">Total</label>        
    </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

In your code '.soma' doesn't update, since it is never targeted when changing the other inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of use `blur` you can use `change` and trigger change with `change()`  when change the value like:

```js
$(".soma4, .soma5, .soma20").blur(function() {

  var total1 = 0;
  var total = 0;
  var total2 = 0;
  var selector = $(this)
  selector.closest(".test").find(".soma4").each(function() {
    total1 = total1 + Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));
  });
  selector.closest(".test").find(".soma5").each(function() {
    total = total + Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));
  });
  selector.closest(".test").find(".soma20").each(function() {
    total2 = total2 + Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));
  });

  total3 = total * total1;
  total4 = total2 / 100;
  total5 = total3 * total4;
  total6 = total3 - total5;
  selector.closest(".test").find(".sub3").val(total6.toFixed(2));
  selector.closest(".test").find(".sub3").change();
});
$('.soma').on('change', function() {
  var total = 0;

  $(".soma").each(function() {
    total = total + Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));
  });

  $("#sub").val(total.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form role="form" class="limp5">
  <div class="test">
    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
      <input type="text" class="form-control1 Preco1 alinha soma4" name="Qttd" id="Qttd" required>
      <span class="form-highlight"></span>
      <span class="form-bar"></span>
      <label class="label3" for="Qttd">Quantidade</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-1" style="width: 11.099999995%; flex: 0 0 11.099%;max-width: 11.099%;">
      <input type="text" class="form-control1 Preco1 alinha soma5" name="Uniit" id="Uniit" required>
      <span class="form-highlight">€</span>
      <span class="form-bar"></span>
      <label class="label3" for="Uniit">Preço Unitário</label> </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
      <input type="text" class="form-control1 soma20 alinha" name="Descoonto" id="Descoonto" required>
      <span class="form-highlight">%</span>
      <span class="form-bar"></span>
      <label class="label3" for="Descoonto">Desconto</label> </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
      <input type="text" class="form-control1 soma alinha sub3" name="Vallor" id="Vallor" required>
      <span class="form-highlight">€</span>
      <span class="form-bar"></span>
      <label class="label3" for="Vallor">Total</label> </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control alinha" name="sub" id="sub">
      <span class="form-highlight">$</span>
      <span class="form-bar"></span>
      <label class="label3" for="sub">Total</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```